# parsing a path based on regex - Python

Tags: python, regex, amazon-s3

I'm trying to scan an `Amazon S3` bucket, in order to search if a new version of our installer has been posted:

The bucket scan returns me something like:

```
versions/
versions/4.4.1.2/
versions/4.4.1.2/Installer.sh
versions/4.4.2.11/
versions/4.4.2.11/Installer.sh
versions/4.5.0.10a/
versions/4.5.0.10a/Installer.sh
versions/4.5.0.12a/
versions/4.5.0.12a/Installer.sh
```

I only need to get the `<{d}.{d}.{d}.{d}{a-z]}>` part between `versions` ... how do I parse that using regex in Python?

Comment: What is your expected output from the above?

Comment: `line.split('/')[1]` ?

Comment: try:line.split ('/')[1]  except: pass

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use **re** module:

> ```
> import re
> text = "versions/4.5.0.10a/"
> re.search('\d+\.\d+\.\d+\.\d+[a-z]', text).group()
> Output: '4.5.0.10a'
> ```

Answer (score 1):

```
("versions/4.4.1.2/").split("/")[1]
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do this through Positive lookahead and lookbehind.

```
>>> s = "versions/";
>>> m = re.compile(r'(?<=/).*?(?=/)')
>>> re.search(m, s)
>>> s = "versions/4.4.1.2/";
>>> re.search(m, s).group()
'4.4.1.2'
>>> s = "versions/4.4.1.2/Installer.sh";
>>> re.search(m, s).group()
'4.4.1.2'
```